# How to use the load function in Octave not knowing the variable name of the saved data?

Tags: io, load, octave

I have several 100 *.mat files with matrices with same shapes. But over time this matrices were saved with different names. Lets say for this example a or b.

How can I now load and process this data without knowing the name using a new name instead?

An if condition is not an option, because there are too many different names.

I already tryed:

```
data = load('example_file.mat')
```

but then I need again the old variable names to access the matrices with data.a or data.b ...

What I need is something like:

```
load('example_file.mat') as matrix
```

Is this possible in Octave?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your attempt

```
data = load('example_file.mat')
```

is the right start. You can examine `data` to find out what variables it contains. Assuming there’s always a single matrix in the MAT-file,

```
names = fieldnames(data);
data = data.(names{1});
```